# pgfplots - How can I use 'nodes near coords' with multiple data values for one tick?

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

When using displaying multiple values for a tick and then activating the display of the values/coordinates, things get messy. This is why I want to display the values inside of the bar. Or on the right of the very bar they belong to, but I can't get it to work, the vertical alignment is always centered to the tick.

One possibility could be to use the `nodes...`-options for each `\addplot`-command and then align them by `above right=XYpt` for the blue bar and `below right` vice versa. But that is thrown out the window if I decide to resize the plot a little bit.

### Picture of the problem

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
amsmath,
tikz,
pgfplots,
pgfplotstable,
}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Process,ValueA,ValueB
1,66,70
2,66,40
3,24,20
4,52,60
5,64,30
6,12,10
}{\tableabcdef}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[
%
height=6cm,
%
xlabel={Force in N},
ylabel={Process \#},
%
xbar,
%
/pgf/bar width=5pt,
%
ytick=data,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align={left},
every node near coord/.style={fill=white, font=\tiny, inner sep=1pt},
]
\addplot+ table [x=ValueA, y=Process] {\tableabcdef};
\addplot+ table [x=ValueB, y=Process] {\tableabcdef};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are overriding the style of the nodes so you need `/.append style` instead

Modifying only these lines

```
nodes near coords align={right},
every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny, inner sep=1pt},
```

leads to

[image]